# to find the order of $G ∩ H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebra-precalculus

Consider the multiplicative group $S = \{z : |z| = 1\} ⊂ \Bbb C$. Let $G$ and $H$ be subgroups of order $8$ and $10$ respectively then to find the order of $G ∩ H$.

$o(G ∩ H)$ must divide both $o(G)$ and $o(H)$ and hence divide $\gcd(8,10) = 2$.

Having confusion about the the order of $G ∩ H$. Will it be $1$ or $2$?

Comment: I don't see a question...

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, order of $G \cap H$ is 1 or 2. We will prove that it is 2. To see that, note that $S$ is abelian, so $G,H$ also are abelian.

There are two abelian groups order 10: $Z_{10}$ and $Z_{2} \times Z_{5}$. Element of order $2$ is in $Z_{10}$ and $Z_{2} \times Z_{5}$, so element of order $2$ is in $G < S$. There is only one element order 2 in $S$ - it is $-1$, so $-1 \in G$.

Next, consider group $H$. Order of any element in that group divides $8$, so any element of that group is $2,4 or 8$th root of unity. Choose any element $z \in H$:

If $z$ is 2nd root of unity, then $z=-1$,
If $z$ is 4th root of unity, then $z^2=-1$
If $z$ is 8th root of unity, then $z^4=-1$

so $-1 \in H$. So $-1 \in G \cap H$.